# Not getting correct answers from very simple functions

Tags: c++

Okay, so I'm a complete noob. I'm trying my hand at Project Euler to get better at C++. I'm doing problem #1, but I'm not getting the correct output. When I run it, I get that numTotalThree is -3, and numTotalFive is -5, and that numTotal is 0. There's something wrong with my functions, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong. How do I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int amount = 1000;
    int numOfThree = amount / 3;
    int numOfFive = amount / 5;
    int numTotalThree = 0;
    int numTotalFive = 0;
    int numTotal = numTotalThree + numTotalFive;

    cout << numOfThree << endl;
    cout << numOfFive << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i <= numOfThree; i++)
    {
        numTotalThree += numTotalThree + 3;
    }

    cout << numTotalThree << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i <= numOfFive; i++)
    {
        numTotalFive += numTotalFive + 5;
    }

    cout << numTotalFive << endl;

    cout << numTotal << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. It would be more helpful if your question was self-contained - what is the requirement?

Comment: Oh, sorry. The variables numTotalThree and numTotalFive are giving wrong answers when they are outputted. There's something wrong with my functions, but I'm not sure what I've done wrong. How do I fix this?

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer that belongs in the question. Please move it there (and thanks for responding, btw).

Comment: Its time to Learn how to debug.

Comment: @qwr: Got any resources that I can learn from?

Comment: @BrandonHoutzer type `Project Euler` in the search box of this website. You'll likely be surprised how many other people have asked similar questions about their problems. When starting out it always helps to see *correct* code. (and note that one answer in particular below precisely answers this question *and* comments on why you're doing more work than you need to. See if you can find it).

Comment: @WhozCraig: Well, considering that you're the only poster who's been here for around ten minutes, and DrM has a single upvote, my bet is that it's on DrM. I did, however, answer him and tell him why I wasn't doing too much work. I will search for Project Euler, though. Thanks.

Comment: @Brandon Houtzer  To learn debugging with modern IDEs is too simple. Just on debug mode put breakpoint at startup of the code. Then step through code to see what is your code doing. Search for how to debug videos and so on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
int sum = 0;

for (int i =0; i < 1000; ++i){
    if(i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0){
        sum += i;
    }
}
```

Later edit: I don't know why you want to count the numbers divisible with 3 or 5 that are less than 1000. The problem (Project Euler - Problem 1) asks for the sum of all the numbers less than 1000, divisible with 3 or 5.

Comment: To use them in a for loop that would add either 3 or 5 each time that the loop is executed. The amount of that type of number that is found that is less than 1000 is what governs how many times the loop executes.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not a functional language it's procedural - that means you have to do things in order.  When you do this:

```
int numTotalFive = 0;
int numTotal = numTotalThree + numTotalFive;
```

It will be executed then and there and not again when numTotalThree and numTotalFive are updated.  If you don't touch it again that's the value that will be output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea to go on:

Check how many are divisible by three by checking that the remainder %==0. Do the same for five, and then for both of them. Subtract from the total of the first two the number that is divisible by both to get an accurate answer.

```
int divisibleByThree=0; 
int divisibleByFive=0;
int divisibleByBoth=0;
int total;

for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    if (i%3==0)
        divisibleByThree++;
    if (i%5==0)
        divisibleByFive++;
    if (i%5==0) && i%5==0)
        divisibleByBoth++;
}

    total = divisibleByThree + divisibleByFive - divisibleByBoth;
    return total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your

`numTotalThree` is overflowing for `n` in [0, 333]

- 3/2*(-2 + 2<sup>n</sup>)

Similarly `numTotalFive` for `n` in [0, 200]

- 5/2*(-2 + 2<sup>n</sup>)

So you're seeing negative values.

As other suggested you probably need to revisit your logic.

All you need is just to sum up the numbers in [0,1000] that are divisible by 3 or 5

```
size_t total =0;
for (size_t x =0; x < 1000; x++){
    if( (x % 3 == 0) || (x % 5 == 0) ){
        total += x;
    }
}
```